# Determinant of matrix with zero diagonal and some structure

Tags: matrices, determinant

$$|A|={\begin{vmatrix} 0& a_1&a_2&\cdots&a_n\\
a_1&0&a_2&\cdots&a_n\\
a_2&a_1&0&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&a_n\\
a_n&a_{n-1}&\cdots&a_1&0
\end{vmatrix}}_{n+1}$$

---

Please give me some hints or something that relates this to me . Thank in advance! I have tried it many times on this exercise. So now please help me about this.

Comment: let $n=2$, then observe the pattern, you may apply induction to prove the determinant.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not following the pattern here. The second column seems to consist mostly of $a_1$s, and a $0$, but ends on $a_{n-1}$? Similarly for the third column? Could you double check your matrix to see if this is really how it's defined?

Comment: @user847970 Look at the upper triangular and lower triangular parts separately.

Comment: I have edited it $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is true, but step 4 isn't. I'm not sure how to fix this as yet.

---

Observe the following (fill in gaps as needed).

1. Clearly $ \sum a_i$ is an eigenvalue with the all 1's eigenvector.
2. The determinant is a degree $n$ polynomial in the variables $a_i$.
3. Taking the difference of the first and second rows, $ a_1$ is a factor of the determinant.
4. (This is true only for $k=1, 2$. I thought it generalizes but doesn't.) Taking the difference of the first and $k+1$th row, $a_k$ is a factor of the determinant.
5. Hence, the determinant is of the form $k \times (\sum a_i ) \prod (a_i)$ for some constant $k$.
6. Find the term $ a_n \prod a_i$ to show that $k = (-1)^n$.

Conclusion: The determinant is $ (\sum a_i ) \prod (-a_i)$

Comment: Can you try to use Elementary operation?

Comment: @PetterGreen Why?

Comment: Should give him a full solution as I think it is useful for him to find out this ?

Comment: Can we use elementary operations on this exercise ?

Comment: @PetterGreen Maybe. If you try it hard enough, you might be able to force out an ERO approach. Give it a try.

Comment: Ok do you have other methods on this exercise ?

Comment: @PetterGreen See the question i linked above.

Comment: Yeah I saw but it has a bit different from above .